Iterating over a HashMap using Iterator interface
I am trying to find the unique number of occurrences of each value in the array. I am putting all occurrences of an element in the HashMap. I want to check whether any two adjacent values are the same in HashMap.
I have tried using the Iterator interface to iterate but there seems something missing
class Solution {
    public boolean uniqueOccurrences(int[] arr) {
        boolean uni = true;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        
        for (int a : arr) {
            if (hm.containsKey(a)) {
                hm.put(a, hm.get(a) + 1);
            } else {
                hm.put(a, 1);
            }
        }

        // Iterate over the HashMap entries
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = hm.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it.next().getValue() == it.getValue()) {
                uni = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        return uni;
    }
}


what do you mean by there is something missing? it.next().getValue() == it.getValue() what do you expect this to do? if you call next() the iterator will move next.

Also, HashMaps are unordered. If you really wanted to compare adjacent values and want your output to be consistent use a linkedhashmap

The previous two comments should help a lot. But, if you still need help, the question could use some clarification. Considering adding an example contents of arr [] with an example of expected output. It might help to explain why the expected result is correct. The code for creating a frequency distribution of the contents of arr[] appears to be correct. As far as I can tell, you want to find out if all counts (frequency of occurrences) are the same or if some values of arr[] occur more than other values of arr[].

Define "unique number of occurrences". All this method does is return a boolean.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’re fine with helping with short code that doesn’t work as expected. When asking about that, please be very precise about the parameter you pass to your method (perhaps a couple of examples if necessary) and the expected and the observed result. Neither of this seems to be in your question as it currently stands. And as you can read from the comments, people have had trouble understanding what you meant.

See the following with a TreeMap. I realised that a LinkedHashMap may not be that good because it follows order of insertion, and in your case, you might want to order it by the value of the keys. Though if you use a hashmap or linkedhashmap, you can probably just get the keys and sort it before doing anything else.
Think over the difference in how the iterator value is handled. Also, I only compare the values so long as I can ensure there are valid values to compare.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2,3, 2,3,1,1,1,3,4};
        boolean bool = uniqueOccurrences(arr);
        System.out.println(bool);
        System.out.println(uniqueOccurrencesMap(arr));
    }
    
    public static boolean uniqueOccurrences(int[] arr) {
        boolean uni = true;
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new TreeMap<>();
        
        for (int a : arr) {
            if (hm.containsKey(a)) {
                hm.put(a, hm.get(a) + 1);
            } else {
                hm.put(a, 1);
            }
        }

        // Iterate over the HashMap entries
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = hm.entrySet().iterator();
        Integer current = null, previous = null;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            previous = current;  //what was previously current is now previous
            current = it.next().getValue();  //get next value as current
            if (!(current == null || previous == null)) {  //if any value is null, not comparable
                if (current == previous) {
                    uni = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return uni;
    }
    
    public static TreeMap<Integer,Integer> uniqueOccurrencesMap(int[] arr) {
        boolean uni = true;
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new TreeMap<>();
        
        for (int a : arr) {
            if (hm.containsKey(a)) {
                hm.put(a, hm.get(a) + 1);
            } else {
                hm.put(a, 1);
            }
        }

        // Iterate over the HashMap entries
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = hm.entrySet().iterator();
        Integer current = null, previous = null;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            previous = current;  //what was previously current is now previous
            current = it.next().getValue();  //get next value as current
            if (!(current == null || previous == null)) { //if any value is null, not comparable
                if (current == previous) {
                    uni = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return hm;
    }

output:

true
{1=4, 2=2, 3=3, 4=1}

